# add crontab daemon

Tags: perl, bash, sockets, cron

I'm trying to simulate a socket client using simple perl program.

## **socket client:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#path: /home/nuthan/client1
use IO::Socket;
my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET ( PeerAddr => 'xx.xx.xx.xx',  PeerPort => '11050',     Proto => 'tcp',  );
die "Could not create socket: $!\n" unless $sock;
    use POSIX 'strftime';
$time=strftime("%H%M%S",localtime) . "\n";
$date=strftime("%d%m%y",localtime)."\n";
$data="#00000##0#0000#AUT#1#V#07734.7000,E,1259.5355,N,000.00,288#$date#$time##";
print $data;
print $sock "$data";
close($sock);
```

---

### **command:** bash script to execute

```
#!/bin/bash
#path: /bin/server
set PATH=/usr/bin/perl
export PATH
/home/nuthan/client1
#perl home/nuthan/client1
```

---

## **crontab command:**

Run this socket client every 60 secs.

```
* * * * * server 2>&1 >> /var/log/client.log
```

**Error:** Finally, i get this Error!!!

```
No command 'bin' found, did you mean:
 Command 'win' from package 'wily' (universe)
 Command 'tin' from package 'tin' (universe)
 Command 'bip' from package 'bip' (universe)
 Command 'bing' from package 'bing' (universe)
 Command 'bins' from package 'bins' (universe)
bin: command not found
```

WHERE AM I GOING WRONG!!!!? please help!!!

Comment: Your error and posted code don't seem to match. It thinks you're running a `bin` command, which should not happen with the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set PATH to the perl executable but instead to the directories containing the tools you want to use, e.g.

```
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply @Sorpigal.Now, i get this `codebunzip2: bunzip2: cannot execute binary file`

Comment: instead of running via bin command, i tried running `* * * * * /home/nuthan/perl client1 2>&1 >> /var/log/client.log` I get the same error

Comment: `/bin/perl /home/nuthan/client1`?

Answer (score 0):

@TLP Thanks for ur help. Got it working!!!

**bash:**

```
  #!/bin/sh
  set PATH=/usr/bin/perl
  export PATH=/bin:/bin
  /home/nuthan/clients/client1
```

---

**cron command:**

```
 * * * * * /usr/bin/perl /bin/client1 2>&1 >> /home/nuthan/logs/client1.log
```

logging client @ /home/nuthan/logs/client1.log